# Sequence of complex numbers with $e^{in!}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I have to show that a sequence is convergent and I need to find their limits. So far so good, but this task has been giving me trouble:

$$z_n = 3^{-n}e^{in!}$$

It's clear that the $3^{-n}$ tends to 0, but I can't tell nearly as clearly what is going on in combination with $e^{in!}$. I want to intuitively say that everything tends to 0 because of $3^{-n}$, but I really doubt it and wouldn't be able to explain it outside of that anyway.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$|z_n|\leq \frac{1}{3^n}.$$

Comment: I think that solves the problem, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome :-)

Comment: What's up with the "<" part?

Comment: Is not $|z_n |=1/3^n$?

Comment: @user: if $a=b$, in particular, $a\leq b$.

Comment: That's true. As well as inequality $|z_n|\ge 1/3^n$.

Comment: @user: could you please precise the aim of your comment ?

Comment: If $a=b$ identically there is no need to write $a\le b$ as it can only cause a misleading idea that $a=b$ is not an identity.

Comment: @user : Thanks a lot for your very constructive comment. I'll know it for the next time. Indeed, I should have been more precise and put the equality. I'm so sorry if you had any confusion. You probably should put it as an answer ? Just in case someone else could make this confusion.

Comment: There is no need for this considering our agreement on the subject.